# SQLite SELECT query - GROUP CONCAT column based on another column's value

Tags: sql, sqlite

How do I get a WHERE inside a GROUP CONCAT operator to be dependent on another column in the query? In this instance what needs to happen is the `score_list`'s values are taken from the scores for the pertinent candidate. In MySQL I was able to use this by using an alias (SELECT candidate_id as id .... WHERE scores.candidate_id = id...), in SQLite I get "no such column".

```
SELECT candidate_id, 
        first_name || ' ' || last_name AS 'name',
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score) 
            FROM scores 
            WHERE scores.candidate_id = *NEEDS TO BE CANDIDATE_ID* 
                AND scores.category_id = 1 
            ORDER BY scores.judge_id
        ) AS score_list
FROM scores 
    JOIN candidates 
        ON candidates.id = scores.candidate_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try aliasing your tables.

```
SELECT oute.candidate_id, 
        oute.first_name || ' ' || oute.last_name AS 'name',
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(inne.score) 
            FROM scores inne
            WHERE inne.candidate_id = oute.candidate_id
                AND inne.category_id = 1 
            ORDER BY inne.judge_id
        ) AS score_list
FROM scores oute 
    JOIN candidates 
        ON candidates.id = oute.candidate_id
```